# How to change value of object which is inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that contains a set of objects And in these objects I want to change the value of a property :

```
var array=[{a:1, b:false}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:false}]
```

I want the propriety **b** to be **true** everywhere

```
var array=[{a:1, b:true}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:true}]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change current array use this:

```js
var array=[{a:1, b:false}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:false}]
array.forEach((obj) => {
   return obj.b = true
})

console.log(array)
```

But if you want still have previous array, try this:

```js
var array=[{a:1, b:false}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:false}];

const newArray = array.map((obj) => ({ ...obj, b: true }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a loop with `map`:

```
const newArr = array.map((item) => ({ ...item, b: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use two possible approaches:

1. you can use `forEach` as follow:

```
yourArray.forEach(item=>item.b = true);
```

2. or if you want to build new array use `map` as follow:

```
const updatedArray = temp.map(item=>{...item, b:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can achieve the result:

1. **Using `forEach`**:

```js
var array=[{a:1, b:false}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:false}]
array.forEach((obj) => {
   return obj.b = true
})

console.log(array)
```

2. **Using `map`**:

```js
var array=[{a:1, b:false}, {a:2, b:true}, {a:3, b:false}];

const result = array.map((item) => ({ ...item, b: true }));

console.log(result);
```